# Isotope + search + filterings with two sections

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the filtering work with two elements and search.

I've only got one element to work..

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
        buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         return false;
    });

  $('.slidein').each( function( i, slidein ) {
    var $slidein = $( slidein );
    $slidein.on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
      $slidein.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      $( this ).addClass('active');
    });
  });
```

You can see a test here what I mean. Someone how know to fix it?

The search filtering working.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xh4F/

Answer (score 0):

`$("#filters")` only returns the first elements with the `id` of `"filters"`. Using `$(".slidein")` returns both elements and works great.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xh4F/1/

```
//Use $(".slidein") !!
$('.slidein').on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
});
```

If you want to instead use a different filter for each `.slidein` element, then use different `id`s for each `.slidein` element and use two different `buttonFilter` variables.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xh4F/3/

```
var buttonFilter1 = "*", buttonFilter2 = "*"; //Use _two_ filters for _two_ different categories.

var $container = $('.portfolio-items').isotope({
  [...]
  filter: function() {
    [...]
    //Check both of the button filters.
    var buttonResult = $this.is( buttonFilter1 ) && $this.is( buttonFilter2 );
    [...]
  },
  [...]
});

[...]
$('#countries').on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
    //For the first filter, set buttonFilter1.
    buttonFilter1 = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
});

$('#nums').on( 'click', 'a.filter', function() {
    //For the second filter, set buttonFilter2.
    buttonFilter2 = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: No.. What I mean is to get two search field to work.. [http://jsfiddle.net/hLdD8/](http://jsfiddle.net/hLdD8/)

Comment: Or have 1 search field with two different search methods. :)

Comment: Oh Thanks man!!! But I have one problem.. Is it possible to only search on the whole word. I mean.. If I have a search tag how has "skate" and another how have "te" If I search on Te, I just want stores with TE shows up! and if i hit Skate, only stores how has "Skate" ??

Your the best!

Comment: when I search on Te, Skate shows up to. I look in my console and I got this when I searched on "skate" "undefined /skate/gi"

Comment: Oh, It was the console.log :) But it is impossible to only get the search word , if I type TE, only tags white tag TE shows up?, not all like skaTE/winTEr @Noble Mushtak

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you just want the `te` tag or tags that start with `te` if `te` is searched?

Comment: If I search on te, I only want the tags with te in shows up. And if i hit winter I want only tags with name winter :) @noble mushtak

Comment: Look here at this JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/CqZ9S/](http://jsfiddle.net/CqZ9S/)

Comment: Nope :(, The items disappears If I search in the tag input. I want like you say "tags that start with te if te is searched" only boxes with Te shows up :)

Comment: You see my tags in the box data-tag="Te Price Sweden" if I hit someone of them I want only this to show up :) but it seems to be impossible:( for me...

Comment: Look at the comments in the code. Uncomment the one you want to use and then comment out the rest.

Comment: Yes Iknow, But it still seems not to work, to search on the Rest of the tags, only the Tags in start. of data-tag="Te.. data-tag="Sun.. etc.. @Noble Mushtak

Comment: If you test and search on just "Sweden" you see what happend. :/

Too search like this "Te Price.. etc" It will works. But not just "Price"

Comment: Oh...OK! I didn't know that the tags were separated by spaces instead of it just being one tag. How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/CqZ9S/2/

Comment: I made this, and it seems to work! http://jsfiddle.net/SMrSq/ :) Look know and try to hit any tag! ;) @NobleMustak

Comment: Do you know how to make a combination filtering with data-filter-group? @NobleMustak

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/SdUQ5/ I want it to this but on click. http://jsfiddle.net/Jp3hN/

Comment: I'm not experienced with Isotope, so I don't think I'll be able to help you anymore. Sorry!

Comment: Oh Thanks alot! You have been helpful for me! Great work @NobelMustak